# rake aborted! PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "pages" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help debugging an error I'm having in deploying my Rails 4 app to heroku following a fork to create a staging environment.

During compiling, I get the error:

```
rake aborted!
       PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pages" does not exist
```

I've run the command to reset the database:

```
    heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --confirm welivecontent-staging
Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL (DATABASE_URL)... done
```

I then run (with trace so you can see results):

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app welivecontent-staging --trace
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.9204
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
marks-mbp-2:wlc markwalker$ 

heroku restart --app welivecontent-staging
Restarting dynos... done
```

I then try to push again...and get the same error.

When I try `heroku run rake db:setup --app welivecontent-staging` I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:831:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:548:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:73:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create_database_url'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"sometext", "password"=>"sometext", "port"=>5432, "database"=>"sometext", "host"=>"sometext.compute-1.amazonaws.com"}
/app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter /app/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
```

It might be worth mentioning I have definitely migrated and pushed all migrations to the master branch; and that I am using delayed_job and foreman in the my app (as they may be involved in the issue somehow).  I also cannot push to heroku master now as I get the same error.

I'd really appreciate any pointers on this as I'm going round and round in circles.

UPDATE:

I've destroyed both heroku apps, and then recreated a new one, but the error still happened.

I then verified if there was a wlc_production database by running `psql` - it said there wasn't, so I created one using `createdb wlc_production` and verified that it was created.

Next I tried RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile to test if it compiles locally, and received the same error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pages" does not exist`, so I tried to migrate the database with `heroku run rake db:migrate` and got a new error:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
```

So i figured maybe I didn't have a Rakefile (I do) or that my ruby version is not up-to-date, but I confirmed that I'm using my default ruby version 2.0.0p353.  To be sure my gems are also using this, I did `rvm gemset create 2.0.0p353 wlc` and created then defaulted this new gemset, and ran bundle install.

I committed my changes...and still nothing.

If I run `git push heroku master` I run into the error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
```

If I try `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get the error: `No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)`

Running `rake db:schema:load` doesn't create an error, I get the following:

```
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0175s
-- enable_extension("hstore")
   -> 0.0027s
-- create_table("active_admin_comments", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.4491s
.........
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0450s
```

but neither does it help stop the errors/solve the problem.  Again, any pointers/suggestions/help based on update info very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `rake db:schema:load` ?

Comment: I've managed to get that to work now - but then what?  The same errors from above still happen.  Is there a second step I need to follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, dropping the 'pages' table and recreating it with a fresh migration solved the issue.  No idea why.

Answer (score 3):

I would run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

I don't think the "pages" table is created in your staging environment yet.

Comment: worked for me even though rails told me that this function is deprecated because rails now "maintains your test schema automatically"!

Comment: Also worked for me with same deprecation message in Rails 4.1.4